# How are the reference images that have front and side view called?

Tags: modeling, image

How should I call this type of reference images and is there any easier way to find the than just looking up something like "character reference front and side view" on Google?
[image]

Comment: I know them as "3d turnaround", "character turnaround" and "model sheet"

Comment: it's also called "blueprint"